# Kill a mob without death animation?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to kill a mob without death animation by either hiding it or "killing" it? I want to kill rabbits, so this is the command:

```
/kill @e[type=Rabbit]
```

There is just one rabbit, so it doesn't need to be all rabbits like in the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can teleport the rabbit down into the void, which will make it disappear instantly, then die due to void damage and perform their death animation out of sight:

```
/tp @e[type=Rabbit] ~ -500 ~
```

Comment: I actually didn't think about that. This is exactly what I need.